# joomla warning message

Tags: joomla

i get this message on my local host running joomla:

Warning: Parameter 1 to modMainMenuHelper::buildXML() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\libraries\joomla\cache\handler\callback.php on line 99

what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

[This forum post contains the answer](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=199&p=1811142), it seems to be a problem with PHP 5.3. Note that Joomla! doesn't officially support 5.3 yet.